# Passing variable from Sinatra module to view?

Tags: ruby, sinatra, erb

I have function in a module in the lib dir of my Sinatra app, that I want to be able to pass
a variable back to a view.

Trying to pass it like :

```
@errorMessage = params["testing error"]
erb :error
```

Bring the error erb that's in ../views from the lib directory, but does not show the errorMessage var.

erb code :

```
<p> Error message : <% @errorMessage %></p>
```

Anyone have any idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should be `<%= @errorMessage %>` and not `<% @errorMessage %>`.

Comment: aah dammm, cannot believe I missed that! Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You can try using :locals

```
erb :error, :locals => {:errorMessage => "My message"}
```

And then use errorMessage as a variable inside your template.